# SSMS Searching for a Column

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012

How do I look for a certain column in a Database with 100+ tables?

For instance, in the frontend, I see a tab with displayed data..

```
A information with columns = email's, mailbox, note1, sent dt/tm, note2 etc.. but in the DB there are about 100+ Tables (messy),
```

I just want to find the table that includes the columns of the A information with out expanding the columns of each table to investigate on where columns = email's, mailbox, note1, sent dt/tm, note2 etc.. Is there an easy way to do this on SQL Server Management studio?

Comment: I suggest this tool http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try information schema:

```
Select *
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where Column_Name like '%Col%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sp_msforeachdb 'USE ?;  Select *
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where Column_Name like ''%Col%'''
```